# Ajax form submit, event listener and change submit button type

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have a single page website with a tabbed form where the visitor uses a button to progress through. On the last tab I want to change the button type to `submit` and use AJAX to submit the form.

Each tab has a next button like this.

```
<button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Continue</button>
```

When the visitor reaches the last tab I use javascript to change the text value of the button.

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
```

I'd like to use AJAX to help submit the form without a page reload. I add the following to change the `type` from `button` to `submit`.

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").type = "submit";
```

In my AJAX script I have this event listener

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  // ...
```

When my last tab loads I think the AJAX script (and the form handler script specified in my form's `action`) runs before the Submit button is clicked.

I know this because my form submission error displays on the web page.

If I then submit the form the AJAX doesn't run but the form handler script specified in my form's `action` does.  I know this because the form handler script loads in the browser window and I receive the form contents via an email notification.

I don't understand why:
 - AJAX runs when the last tab is reached
 - but AJAX doesn't run when I press submit

Comment: Hi, just a clarification, are all your tabs in one form?

Comment: Yes @Bosco all the tabs are on the same single form.

Answer (score 0):

I think that after your click handler returns, it notices that the button has changed to a submit button, so it submits the form. Put `e.preventDefault()` in the click handler that changes the button type.

Another way to code this would be not to change the button type, but just have the click handler test whether you're on the last tab, and do the AJAX submission there.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by adding a submit button which remains hidden until the last slide. And then hiding the continue button on the last slide too.

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "inline";
```